# Why list comprehension elements differ from generator elements, in Pycharm iPython prompt?

Tags: python, pycharm

When pasted into a commadline iPython prompt, the following code

```
TFN = [True, False, None]
for q in TFN:
    gen   = (c for c in TFN if c==q)
    lcomp = [c for c in TFN if c==q]
    print list(gen), "\t",list(lcomp)
```

... produces:

```
gen     lcomp
[True]  [True]
[False] [False]
[None]  [None]
```

(the printed columns of elements are not identical as you might expect).
[image]

However, when pasted into an IntelliJ PyCharm iPython prompt, this changes to:

```
[None]  [True]
[None]  [False]
[None]  [None]
```

To reproduce:

- Set the breakpoint as shown below:
- Select the file, run click, select "Debug..."
- Wait for the breakpoint to be hit
- Select the code as shown. ALT+SHIFT+E to execute.

you'll see different output the second time!

[image]

Why?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. What is `TFN`? Why are you iterating over it multiple times?

Comment: Without insight into the structure you're using, we have no way to reproduce the problem, and little way to help you.

Comment: My bad. Missing variable from the minimal example was missing. Is now fixed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga -- I am only iterating over TFN once.

Comment: @user48956 no you aren't, you iterate over it in the for-loop, and then each iteration of the for-loop, you iterate over it again `[c for c in TFN if c==q]`...

Comment: In any case, I cannot reproduce your output, it outputs what one would expect. So again, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Indeed - and it helpful.
OK -- this bug is wackier than expected. I also could not reproduce the original description when running from command-line python or when run by pasting into an iPython prompt. The problem only manifests when pasting the code into a PyCharm IPython prompt. Detailed reproduction steps and screenshots above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PyCharm develops were able to reproduce this. It is a bug in PyCharm:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FPY-36512